# How to remove that blue box (do you call it "box focus"?) that appears upon clicking the button?

Tags: css

Every time I click on every button, there is this blue box that surrounds the button. I want to remove it. Is there a way to make it transparent?

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/hackernoon/removing-that-ugly-focus-ring-and-keeping-it-too-6c8727fefcd2  ,  https://www.oreilly.com/content/proposing-css-input-modality/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **outline** property:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp